# Cannot move VirtualBox window

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, desktop-environments, mate, ubuntu-mate

I have a weired sympton with a fresh Windos 10 guest OS under VirtualBox 5.1.28 under Ubutunu-MATE 16.04:

**I can't move the window at all, when `[x] Auto Capture Keyboard` is on.**

**Neither dragging the outer windows borders** (resize), **nor the titlebar** (indeed just move the virtuabl box. So this is *not* about auto-resize on or off...). If I deactivate the option, things work fine again. (I do not even understand the relation). – sounds like a virtual box bug? Can't reproduce the opposite, but I have been working with virtual box (and Win7 guests) for long, never encountered this until 2 weeks ago.

[image]

But then, common shortcuts I have defined in host and guest, don't work on the guest but rather the host (i.e. WIN-R to get a run programm...). So, *of course* capturing is desirable.

Comment: I have been having this problem too(various guest os's) although for me unchecking "Auto Capture Keyboard" is good enough of a solution for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088850/ubuntu-18-04-in-vm-desktop-does-not-restore-window-size

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I find the same thing when imwheel is running, the utility that allows change to the mouse wheel.  Holding down the Right-Control dows allow VirtualBox windows to be moved around.

Comment: Instant hit.  I couldn't move as described, I did a `killall imwheel`, I instantly could! (not even restart of OS or Virtualbox or anything). Thanx!

Comment: I had to press host key before each move/resize

Answer (score 11):

For some reason, the auto capture of Virtual Box seems to conflict with the way how dragging a window from the title bar works

One easy workaround for this is to press the "Host key" (<kbd>right control</kbd> by default) to temporarily turn off auto capture mode, so you move the window around normally. (The status of keyboard capture, and the Host key, can be seen in the lower right of VirtualBox)

Answer (score 6):

Just uncheck "Auto Capture Keyboard" was enough for me

Comment: Works fine but what if I want that too? LOL

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: We can move a VM window when it has not the focus. No need to press the rigth Ctrl. Here is a video recorded:
https://video.antopie.org/videos/watch/8c69f9e5-d844-4f80-b30d-01456e2fa6eb

Comment: I am not fully getting what you are doing different (sorry. Perhaps because because I have no audio at hand)